# How to fix extra empty lines in files that are downloaded by FileZilla Client and Uploaded by VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp, vscode-extensions, filezilla

I have problem when i upload file to remove server with VS code and extension [SFTP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp)
then if i download same file with FileZilla Client and open with VS code im getting a lot of extra empty lines. How to fix that extra empty line ?

for example if the code i upload via SFTP look like this:

```
<?php
class ControllerApiCart extends Controller {

public function add() {
    $this->load->language('api/cart');

    $json = array();

    if (!isset($this->session->data['api_id'])) {
        $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }
```

when i download the same file with FileZilla Client the code look like this:

```
<?php

class ControllerApiCart extends Controller {

public function add() {

    $this->load->language('api/cart');



    $json = array();



    if (!isset($this->session->data['api_id'])) {

        $json['error']['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');

    }
```

Comment: So did you figure out at what step does the file change? Is it the upload or the download?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the file is change on download when i use FileZilla Client if i download same file via Cpanel -> file manager and open in VS code everything is fine, if i download via FileZilla Client im getting this extra empty lines

Comment: Imo, that a download using completely different API behave differently doesn't prove that it is the FileZilla SFTP download that modifies the file. Anyway, if you are sure that it's SFTP download that modifies the file (and I doubt it), then you do not have a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the first place.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i post the fix of my issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fix this issue by creating .editorconfig file in work directory of my project an insert this code

```
[*]
charset = utf-8

# Use LF (Unix) line endings
[*.{php,js,css,html}]
end_of_line = lf
```